# The link_to that should action a destroy action only calls the `show` action of my Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to implement a simple delete action on my Movie controller, but it simply reloads the page by running the `show` action of the controller.
I generated the routes with `resources :movies`.

`show.html.erb`

```
<section class="admin">
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_movie_path(@movie), class: "button" %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", movie_path(movie),
            data: { turbo_method: :delete , turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
</section>
```

`movies_controller.rb`

```
def destroy
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie.destroy
    redirect_to movies_url, status: :see_other
end
```

There are no errors happening, but I can see in the console that the `show` action is being run instead of `destroy`

I tried deleting the `destroy` action of the controller to see if an error comes up, but it doesn't - the view is not trying to use the `destroy` action.

Comment: Is turbo not active? Because if nothing handles `turbo_method: :delete`, then it's regular GET link.

Comment: I haven't had to activate turbo in the past, any suggestions on how I can check this @SergioTulentsev?

Comment: is this a new app? if there were errors during `rails new`, you might be missing some install steps. if you're using `jsbundling-rails` you need to run `bin/dev` and it should build without errors. `@hotwired/turbo-rails` should be in `app/javascript/application.js`. do your forms submit as `TURBO_STREAM`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use button_to with the method destroy

```
<%= button_to "Delete this movie", @movie, method: :destroy, class:"btn btn-danger" %>
```

PS: I included the class button danger from Bootstrap, but you can remove it if you are not using it.

Comment: `method: :delete`